# Does GetPrimitiveArrayCritical OpenJDK hotspot never copy?

Tags: java-8, java

in the documentation of GetPrimitiveArrayCritical it says that it may copy the array sometimes. The IBM documentation for their JDK says that it will most likely not copy it if the array size is less then the 1/1000 of the heap size. I looked at the code of the function in OpenJDK 8 and it seams that it never copies it but rather it only sets the isCopy to false.
I checked that in the file
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/872e9c4548bf/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp 
at line 4250.
Does that mean that if I use openJDK I won't have a problem with the JVM copying the memory?

P.S. I don't care if my code runs on any other JVM.

Answer (score 1):

I double-checked the OpenJDK 8 sources, and yes, it seems that `GetPrimtiveArrayCritical` indeed never makes a copy. It does not even depend on the garbage collection algorithm. The code in OpenJDK 9 is similar. Whether it is a good idea to rely on this is another question altogether. The similar `GetStringCritical` method started making copies in OpenJDK 9 in many cases (namely, when a byte array is used as the backing array for the string).

Comment: Thank you, just needed somebody to confirm this. I'm about to abuse this a lot :)